# Problem with MPI on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: fortran, mpi

I'm not sure what happened, I think MPI was working well when I first installed ubuntu 22.04. Then I saw I could install also ifortran (not sure if this has affected something), and also mkl.

However, the problem I find now is that when I try to run the code I get this message:

- $ mpirun -n 2 testparalel.x

[proxy:0:0@Dedalus] HYD_spawn
(../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/spawn/intel/hydra_spawn.c:151):
execvp error on file testparalel.x (No such file or directory)

This worked before I've installed the ifort and mkl, not sure if it has something to do with it.
If instead I use a ./ before the program I get:

*$ mpirun -n 2 ./testparalel.x

iam=           0   nproc=           1

iam=           0   nproc=           1

The code is run on different processors as different programs, not as a single MPI program (thats why the "iam" variable is zero in both cases, and the nproc =1, instead of 2).

MPI worked fine before I've installed the intel fortran compiller (mpifort calls gfortran anyway). Moreover, I think that there is some issue with the intel compiller, because the hydra directory it seems to look for when I try to run the program points to intel.

Any idea of what could be going on?

I leave the test code, so you can check it. The problem is not the code, I know that because I've tested it with gfortran before installing the intel fortran compiler. I think the issue was originated when ifort was installed.

```
program test

include 'mpif.h'

call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,iam,ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,nproc,ierr)

print*,'iam=',iam,'  nproc=',nproc

call mpi_finalize(ierr)

stop
end
```

---

No, that's not the problem. As explained before, the program runs when I do:

$:mpirun -n 2 ./testparalel.x

iam= 0 nproc= 1

iam= 0 nproc= 1

But MPI is not running correctly, because if run properly, it should return

iam=0 nproc=2

iam=1 nproc=2

etc. What it seems to be doing is running the same program, repeatedly on each processor, and not occurring all inside the same MPI environment. I don't know if you are familiar with MPI, if you do, you should understand what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

`execvp error on file testparalel.x (No such file or directory)` Seems clear: "testparalel.x" does not exist. Maybe use one more "l" in the word "parallel"?